# Yii2 DatePicker not rendering jquery UI widget

Tags: yii2

I am trying to use yii\jui\DatePicker but for some reason DatePicker is not rendering the jquery ui widget. As a result clicking the input field does not open calendar. Firebug is not showing anything.. any thought about the cause of this?

Here is my code:

```
<?php use yii\jui\DatePicker; ?>

<?=
  DatePicker::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attribute' => 'entryDate',
    'language' => Yii::$app->language,
    'dateFormat' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
  ]);
?>
```

I have tried to implement the above in a new yii2 basic template and it works fine. I wonder what could be the problem in my existing project.

Other components in my view are `yii\helpers\Html` `yii\widgets\ActiveForm`. Below is my view:

```
<?php
  use yii\helpers\Html;
  use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
  use yii\jui\DatePicker;

  $this->title = Html::encode($this->context->getShopNameByUserId(Yii::$app->user->id));
?>
<div class="content">
  <div class="main-content">
    <div class="widget widget-table">
      <div class="widget-header" style="padding-right:0px;">
        <h3><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i> <?= Yii::t('user', 'Add/Edit Coupon') ?></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="widget-content">
        <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]) ?>
        <?=
          DatePicker::widget([
            'model' => $model,
            'attribute' => 'entryDate',
            'language' => Yii::$app->language,
            'dateFormat' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
          ]);
        ?>
        <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('user', 'Save'), ['class' => 'btn btn-custom-primary']) ?>
        <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add the code you are using to render the widget?

Comment: @marche thanks for your time, I just edited my question for more clarifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I've used the Yii2 DatePicker widget previously it's always been in the ActiveField ->widget() method:

```
<?php

echo $form->field($Model, 'entryDate')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [ 'dateFormat' => 'php:d/m/Y', 'options'=> ['class'=>'form-control']])->hint('When does this take place?');

?>
```